# How do I read a yaml file into a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, yaml, jupyter

I have a file from an Open API Spec that I have been trying to access in a Jupyter notebook. It is a .yaml file. I was able to upload it into Jupyter and put it in the same folder as the notebook I'd like to use to access it. I am new to Jupyter and Python, so I'm sorry if this is a basic question. I found a forum that suggested this code to read the data (in my file: "openapi.yaml"):

```
import yaml

with open("openapi.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

This seems to bring the data in, but it is a completely unstructured stream like so:

```
{'openapi': '3.0.0', 'info': {'title': 'XY Tracking API', 'version': '2.0', 'contact': {'name': 'Narrativa', 'url': 'http://link, 'email': '}, 'description': 'The XY Tracking Project collects information from different data sources to provide comprehensive data for the XYs, X-Y. Contact Support:'}, 'servers': [{'url': 'link'}], 'paths': {'/api': {'get': {'summary': 'Data by date range', 'tags': [], 'responses': {'200': {'description': 'OK', 'content': {'application/json': {'schema': {'$ref': '#/components/schemas/covidtata'}}}}}, 'operationId': 'get-api', 'parameters': [{'schema': {'type': 'string', 'format': 'date'}, 'in': 'query', 'name': 'date_from', 'description': 'Date range beginig (YYYY-DD-MM)', 'required': True}, {'schema': {'type': 'string', 'format': 'date'}, 'in': 'query', 'name': 'date_to', 'description': 'Date range ending (YYYY-DD-MM)'}], 'description': 'Returns the data for a specific date range.'}}, '/api/{date}': {'parameters': [{'schema': {'type': 'string', 'format': 'date'}, 'name': 'date', 'in': 'path', 'required': True}], 'get': {'summary': 'Data by date', 'tags': [], 'responses': {'200': {'description': 'OK', 'content': {'application/json': {'schema': {'$ref': '#/components/schemas/data'}}}}}, 'operationId': 'get-api-date', 'description': 'Returns the data for a specific day.'}}, '/api/country/{country}': {'parameters': [{'schema': {'type': 'string', 'example': 'spain'}, 'name': 'country', 'in': 'path', 'required': True, 'example': 'spain'}, {'schema': {'type': 'strin

...etc.
```

I'd like to work through the data for analysis but can't seem to access it correctly. Any help would be extremely appreciated!!! Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing in the output is JSON. This is in a machine-readable format which doesn't need human-readable newlines or indentation. You should be able to work with this data just fine in your code.

Alternatively, you may want to consider another parser/emitter such as [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) which can make dealing with YAML files considerably easier than the package you're currently importing. Print statements with this package can preserve lines and indentation for better readability.